# How can i create a Div Construct from a JS Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I try actually to create a Simple Div Constrct based on a JS Array...
Unfortunately my Way below just shows up the Last Group / Element of the Array, what must be changed to create a repeating Div Construct for each Array Element?

Generated REsult should be like:

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>'val.labelfromelement1'</h3>
  <div class="notimportant">'val.Namefromelement1'</div>
  <h3>'val.labelfromelement2'</h3>
  <div class="notimportant">'val.Namefromelement2'</div>
  <h3>'val.labelfromelement3'</h3>
  <div class="notimportant">'val.Namefromelement3'</div>
  <h3>'val.labelfromelement4'</h3>
  <div class="notimportant">'val.Namefromelement4'</div>
</div>
```

Here is my  actual Code:

```js
var myData = [
   {
    label: "erster",
    id: 0,
    Name:"Ein Name"
    
    },
   {
    label: "zweiter",
    id: 1,
    Name:"Der zweite Name"
    
    },
   {
    label: "dritter",
    id: 2,
    Name:"Dritter Name"
    
    }
  
  ]


$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $.each(myData, function (i, val) {
    myAccordion = "<h3>" + val.label + "</h3><div>" + val.Name + "</div>";
   });
   $("#myAccordionDiv").html(myAccordion);
  
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="myAccordionDiv">

</div>
</body>
```

as you can see, it should result in an accordion that will be automatic increase if a we create a new element in the array (The Array is from a chart)

[image: Final Design]

Any Suggestion? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You might find this plugin useful: https://github.com/ndugger/jQuery.HTMLBuilder.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you only see the last one is because you never initialize the variable `myAccordionDiv` and append each html string in the iterations to it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hz0b6k71/

```
var myAccordion = "";
$.each(myData, function (i, val) {
    myAccordion += "<h3>" + val.label + "</h3><div>" + val.Name + "</div>";
});
$("#myAccordionDiv").html(myAccordion);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good but you have to append all the content of array to"myAccordion" var.

If you change your js code like this it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        var myAccordion;
        $.each(myData, function (i, val) {
            myAccordion += "<h3>" + val.label + "</h3><div>" + val.Name + "</div>";
        });
        $("#myAccordionDiv").html(myAccordion);

    });
```

I hope that will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try appending variable `myAccordion` to `#myAccordianDiv` element within `$.each()`

```js
var myData = [{
    label: "erster",
    id: 0,
    Name: "Ein Name"

  }, {
    label: "zweiter",
    id: 1,
    Name: "Der zweite Name"

  }, {
    label: "dritter",
    id: 2,
    Name: "Dritter Name"

  }

];

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $.each(myData, function(i, val) {
    var myAccordion = "<h3>" + val.label + "</h3><div>" + val.Name + "</div>";
    // append `myAccordion` string to `#myAccordionDiv`
    $("#myAccordionDiv").append(myAccordion);
  });
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="myAccordionDiv">

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with raw javascript:

http://jsbin.com/nofiqiweri/edit?html,js,console,output

you were not storing the data into the myAccordion variable properly.

```
var myData = [
 {
  label: "erster",
  id: 0,
  Name:"Ein Name"               
},
  {
    label: "zweiter",
    id: 1,
    Name:"Der zweite Name"

  },
  {
    label: "dritter",
    id: 2,
    Name:"Dritter Name"
  }

];



  var myAccordion;
  for (var i=0; i<myData.length; i++) {
    myAccordion += '<h3>'+myData[i].label+'</h3><div>'+myData[i].Name+'</div>';
  }
  document.getElementById('myAccordionDiv').innerHTML(myAccordion);
```

Comment: That is not raw javascript. $('#myAccordionDiv').html(myAccordion); or $(function () {});

Answer (score 1):

Bts something like that, could get it run in those few minuts: :/ But look for AngularJS and fill an Object or even better JSON-Object into a table.
Some good Tutorials for this:
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_tables.asp

http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pj5br/

```js
var myData = [{
    label: "erster",
    id: 0,
    Name: "Ein Name"

  }, {
    label: "zweiter",
    id: 1,
    Name: "Der zweite Name"

  }, {
    label: "dritter",
    id: 2,
    Name: "Dritter Name"

  }

]

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.names = myData;);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <title>BlaBlaBla</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="x in names">
      <h3>{{x.Name}}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```